# Firefox: turn off "This file is not commonly downloaded" warning

Tags: firefox, browser, download

After downloading a file, Firefox gives me the following warning:

[image: This file is not commonly downloaded]

How do I turn this off?

Don't make me switch to links.

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, found it.

In about:config, toggle this setting: browser.safebrowsing.downloads.remote.block_uncommon